# When focus on input, getting error: Uncaught TypeError in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input that everytime I focus on it or type something I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.nodeName.toLowerCase is not a function
    at Array.<anonymous> (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2
    at f (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.handlers (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
```

Anyone has any idea what this might mean?

This seems to be where the error is in the jquery file:

```
   filter: {
        TAG: function(a) {
            var b = a.replace(ca, da).toLowerCase();
            return "*" === a ? function() {
                return !0
            }
            : function(a) {
             // HERE
                return a.nodeName && a.nodeName.toLowerCase() === b
            }
        },
```

## HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="kw1">Keyword 1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="kw1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post your html as well

Comment: @WayneAllen done

Answer (score 0):

> toLowerCase() method converts **only** string to lowercase letters.

Thus, have you tried converting `a.nodeName` to string?

```
a.nodeName.toString().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Parse nodeName to String first:**

```
a.nodeName.toString().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The important error part

`Array.<anonymous>`

jQuery returns a collection/array

So, you have to specify the index

```
a[index].nodeName.toLowerCase()
```

or

```
a[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()
```

Check below

```js
console.log($('div')[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()); //=>work 

console.log($('div').nodeName.toLowerCase()); // => error
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35579223/4031815

There was another input in our form named nodeName and it was causing conflict with a jQuery var also named nodeName, so I changed the name to another thing and this fixed the issue